# My break statement is not working in a while loop with an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Trying to figure out how I can make a class or function that will take two numbers and save them to a list, use a break statement to make the second conditional on the answer of the first (and also make sure that the same numbers can’t be used), and I don’t know whether I would use a **repr** or **str** statement to return the whole game every time if I wanted to make a class out of it.

I tried for loops before while loops like(for i in fye, for e in fire), but those would either return integer not iterable and then I made the int(type) into fye = list(int(input("fye"))) and then this would return that object was not compatible with int for operators.

```
>>> def play():
...     fye = None
...     fire = None
...     while fye == None:
...         fye = int(input("What number am I thinking of?"))
...         if fye > 5:
...             print("you got it")
...             fear.append(fye)
...             continue
...         else:
...             print("wrong")
...             break
...     while fire == None:
...         fire = int(input("what number you got now?"))
...         if fire > 15:
...             print("you made it")
...             fear.append(fire)
...         elif fire == fye:
...             print("whoops try again")
...         else:
...             print("you got burnt up")
...
>>> play()
What number am I thinking of?3
wrong
what number you got now?27
you made it
>>> fear
[7, 27]
```

Comment: If you want to have a function get you two numbers, you want `return [fye, fire]` instead of `break`

Comment: "make the second conditional on the answer of the first" - can you explain with example input/output how it should work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that `fye` is immeadiately not None on the first iteration of the loop, so the `break` or `continue` don't do anything meaningful.

```
...     while fye == None:
...         fye = int(input("What number am I thinking of?"))
```

If you want to continuously ask for input until you say `break`, then you would do `while True`

And rather than use a global `fear` variable, after both while loops, you can `return [fye, fire]`